# How to include a file in AAR bundle from Android plugin for gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I am using the experimental Android gradle plugin (0.8.1) and I would like to include custom configuration file in the AAR bundle. This configuration file has nothing to do with Android and is used by external tools. I know that `packagingOptions` has `exclude` but I am looking for `include` or something similar. So far I am considering to open the AAR bundle as a ZIP archive and include the configuration file but I would like to know if there are better options.

Comment: I ended up with calling `aapt` tool to add the file.